# Possible to attach XLS inside DOC file?

Tags: microsoft-office, documents, attachments, xls

Not sure if this is possible in a `.DOC` (I hope it is).
I have seen this done it `.PPTs`

I would like to include reference `.XLS` documents inside one `.DOC` file, doing an **INSERT** `>` **FILE** only inserts gibberish (encoding) and it is not what I want.  Has anyone done this before?

I don't want a `hyperlink` as that would just refer to the file location.
To clarify I **do not** want to insert the contents of the file into the `.DOC`, I want the file icon, which would then be clickable and it would open in Excel.

Need to attach XLS files so that everything is together (I know I could zip all the stuff, but for presentation I would like it all in one file for easy review).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure which version of Office, but with Word 2003, you can do that as follows:

- Insert -> Object...
- On tab "Create from File" click on "Browse" and browse for your Excel file.
- Check "Display as icon" (make sure "Link to file" is NOT checked).
- Click "OK".

[image]

Comment: +1 yep that did it, I was looking at insert Object but somehow missed that method.  Thanks!